# how to select multiple values in list view after accessing the contacts

Tags: android

public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int j, long l) {

```
makeText(this, "Clicked" + j, LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

Comment: your question is not clear, please add some info about the issue, what you trying to do, and what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can take array list of items and `onItemClick` event you can add your selected item into arraylist.

> arraylist.add(selectedItem);

Answer (score 0):

I using this piece of code. To select items in this code the user have first to long click to select first item and after that he can select/unselect more items with short click.

```
private SparseBooleanArray hasClicked = new SparseBooleanArray();

ContactList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

@Override

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));

hasClicked.put(position, false);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

marked++;

ContactList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

if (hasClicked.get(position, true)) {

selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

hasClicked.put(position, false);

marked++;

} else {

selectedItems.remove(adapter.getItem(position));

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

hasClicked.put(position, true);

marked--;

}

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

});

if (marked > 0) {

//gruppe erstellen

} else {

onClickListener();

selectedItems.clear();

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

return true;

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the selected item position in Arraylist but when item is already selected then you can unselect it by removing it from Arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Integer> itemList=new ArrayList<>();     
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int j, long l) {
    if(itemList.contains(j)) {
        itemList.remove(j);
    }
    else {
        itemList.add(j);
    }
}
```